# SOAP XML under Web Services - Magento 1.5.1.0

Tags: magento-1

I have a client that I had to redo his website after he tried upgrading from 1.5.1.0 to 1.7.0.2.

I installed a fresh version of 1.5.1.0 and then copied bits and pieces over from the database like products, sales, categories and customers. I was unable to bring over any extensions without the site breaking. I got his site back up running just fine, but now he is saying that SOAP XML is missing from web services.

I am used to Magento 1.7 so I don't know much about version 1.5.1.0.

Does Magento 1.5.1.0 have SOAP XML under web services? If so why doesn't it show for me? If not how can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 1.5.1.0 does have a SOAP API.
The WSDL for the SOAP API v1 can be accessed like this:
`http://magento-host.dev/api/?wsdl`

The WSDL for the SOAP API v2 can be accessed like this:
`http://magento-host.dev/api/v2_soap/?wsdl`

Relates system configuration settings can be found under
*System > Configuration > Magento Core API*